# ExtJs4.0 create store automatically?

Tags: extjs

Is Ext.data.Store created automatically when app.js is loaded in ExtJs 4.0?
I set autoLoad : true in my store and when app.js has loaded i saw a http request that store is sended.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled : true });
Ext.application({
    name : 'YX',
    enableQuickTips : true,
    autoCreateViewport : true,
    controllers : ['UserController']
});

Ext.define('YX.controller.UserController', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    models : ['User'],
    stores : ['UserStore'],
    views : ['user.List', 'user.Edit'],
    refs : [
        { ref : 'list', selector : 'userlist' },
        { ref : 'edit', selector : 'useredit' }
    ]
});

Ext.define('YX.store.UserStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'YX.model.User',
    autoLoad : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'user/list.do',
        reader : app.ajax.gridReader
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended behavior. If you set `autoLoad: true`, your store will load when the class is created.

If you want your store to load only when used, you need to set `autoLoad: false` and call `store.load()` manually. A good point where to do this would in the `beforerender`evnet of the component that needs your store to display data.